# What is the use of V ref pin in a differential amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, hardware

What is the use of Vref in a differential amplifier?

Will it keep the output below V+=5V (from 0 to 5V) or will it keep the output below reference voltage (Vref) =3V (from 0 to 3V?)

What does unidirectional ground reference output, and what is unidirectional V= referenced output?

[image]
[image]

i refered Google i got some results but iam still confused. kindly help me clearing my confusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is useful to set output DC voltage.

\$V_{REF1} and V_{REF2} \$ are DC voltage and at the input there are two resistors:

[image: schematic]

by doing some calculations:
\$V_{ref out}=\frac{V_{REF1}+V_{REF2}}{2} \$

In the first image, \$ V_{ref1}=V_{ref2}=5 V\$ that means \$V_{ref out}=5 V \$ and this voltage will be amplified by the OpAmp and the output DC voltage will be 4.8V.

In the second image, , \$ V_{ref1}=V_{ref2}=0 V\$ that means \$V_{ref out}=0 V \$ and this voltage will be amplified by the OpAmp and the output DC voltage will be 0.05 V(it is not 0 volt because of offset, typical of the op amp).

For example, if you connect \$V_{ref1}\$ to \$ V_+\$ and \$V_{ref2}\$ to GND, you get \$V_{ref out}=2.5 V \$ without any external voltage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. You mean that When we connect both the Vref to ground the Voutput starts from 0.05 v when we give input as 0 v and vice versa for Vref to 5v. and another doubt is  Vout is based on the maximum Vref value or maximum V+ value.